# Scala test cannot find any test to run

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.0, specs2

I am trying to run some test in scala play framework. Here is the code that I have written

```
package com.sentrana.mmcore.integrationTests

import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._
import org.junit.runner._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.libs.json._

class ApplicationSpec extends Specification with Tags {
  "Application" should {
    "work" in new WithApplication {
      route(FakeRequest(GET, "/boum")) must beNone
    }
  }

}
```

This is the command that I am using to run the test -

`test-only com.sentrana.mmcore.integrationTests.ApplicationSpec`

I am not getting any error. But it is showing me that 0 tests have been.

Comment: Would you have a small project where it is possible to reproduce this issue? Which versions of play and specs2 are you using?

Comment: @Eric, we are using play and spec version 2.

Comment: I am sorry but we don't have any other projects to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Eric, should I edit the question and give you the biuld.sbt file?

Comment: @Eric. please can you give me some suggestions as to how should I proceed?

Comment: Edit question and add versions of Play.

Comment: What you wrote is basically what is supposed to be done. So I/we need more information to help you debug this, like your build.sbt file or the exact output that you are seeing. Also some experimentation on your side wouldn't hurt: try another with another test framework like scalatest, start from a demo project which works and start adding stuff from your project until it doesn't work anymore,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add you test using IntellijIDEA make sure that the file has .scala extension. The IDE does not show errors but the activator cannot find the test because it is searching for scala files.